# ExecutorService+GreenMail

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, javamail, smtp-server, mock

Тестирую отправку сообщений с помощью `JavaMailSender`, который запускается из `ExecutorService` с помощью `submit`, все работает отлично, но в тестах `GreenMail` не получает сообщения, так как заканчивает работу слишком быстро. До этого использовала `execute+awaitTermination` - все проходило на ура. `setServerStartUpTimeout, setServerConnectionTimeout` на любое время для `GreenMail` не помогают. Как можно это решить? или есть другие библиотеки чтобы имитировать `SMTP server`?
Вот код, то что в отправителе

```
notifications.forEach(notification -> {
            Supplier<Boolean> sendingTask = () -> sendNotification(notification);
            CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sendingTask, executorService);
            future.whenComplete((result, ex) -> {
                if (result) {
                    log.info("Successfull");
                }
                if (ex != null) {
                    log.error("Error by sending", ex);
                }
            });
        });
```

Это в тесте

```
def setup() {
        ServerSetup serverSetup = ServerSetupTest.SMTP
        serverSetup.setServerStartupTimeout(50000)
        serverSetup.setWriteTimeout(50000)
        serverSetup.setReadTimeout(50000)
        serverSetup.setConnectionTimeout(50000)

        testSmtp = new GreenMail(serverSetup)
        testSmtp.start()
        javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl()
        javaMailSender.setHost("127.0.0.1")
        javaMailSender.setPort(3025)
    }
```

и в самом тестовом методе
`def messages = testSmtp.getReceivedMessages()` - показывает пустой лист(

Answer (score 0):

так как вы запускаете тестовые запросы асинхронно, то основной поток, запустивший сервер завершается не дожидаясь асинхронных задач. Ожидание запущенных задач можно реализовать разными способами:

- например [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)
- или если время выполнения теста не важно, но нет времени разбираться с CountDownLatch, можно в цикле вызывать `Thread.sleep` и проверять завершение задач вызывая `CompletableFuture.isDone()`

другие предполагаемые (т.к. полного кода теста нет) проблемы:

- JavaMailSenderImpl использует нестандартный SMTP порт (3025), который не конфигурится в serverSetup

Answer (score 0):

Как выше писал Ramiz надо действительно заставить фейк-сервер ждать прихода сообщений. Использовала библиотеку `awailitility`, интегрированную с `Groovy`.